# Password hashing into string hash in C

Tags: c

How can one create a simple password hashing function in C? I know that there is a standard library available, `crypt.h`, and also `openssl/sha.h` But that does not produce a string. I have tried different ways to print the sha256 string, but the string is not the same as other sha256 string of the same word.

The code for hashing into sha256 I have found in a topic on this website:

```
char input[] = "hello";
int length = sizeof(input);
SHA256_CTX context;
unsigned char md[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA256_Init(&context);
SHA256_Update(&context, (unsigned char *)input, length);
SHA256_Final(md, &context);

printf("%02x\n", md); // every time different value: c94ce410, 46d384c0 ..
printf("sizeof md = %zu\n", sizeof(md));
int i;
for(i = 0; i <= sizeof(md); i++) {
    printf("%02x", md[i]); // not a sha256..
    printf("%u", md[i]); // only numeric, not correct..
}
printf("\n");
```

The string that it produces is:
`f3aefe62965a91903610f0e23cc8a69d5b87cea6d28e75489b0d2ca02ed7993c62`

But that is not a sha256 string for `hello`, because it is not recognized by online decryption services. I am using `#include <openssl/sha.h>` for this one.

**Edit:**

Correct settings:

```
int length = strlen(input);
int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(md); i++) {
        printf("%0x", md[i]);
        //printf("%u", md[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Now a correct sha256 hash string is produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your length is wrong. Typedef return the length of a type, here a char array witch is ended by \0. You need to use strlen instead.

Comment: I have tried using `strlen(md)`, but that produces a longer string, also incorrect: `f3aefe62965a91903610f0e23cc8a69d5b87cea6d28e75489bd2ca02ed7993c62feaef390915a96e2f010369da6c83ca6ce875b48758ed2a02cd9b3c99d72e300`

Comment: No I don't talk about md length, but the input length

Comment: I have changed to `strlen(input)` above as well. Now it looks more correct, but there are 2 characters at the end of the resulting string hash: `ba`. `2cf24dba5fb0a3e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e7343362938b9824ba`

Comment: Nevermind, I think it works, it was a matter of using correct settings in the for loop: correct string: `2cf24dba5fb0a3e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e7343362938b9824` Thanks!